# How to list indexes created for table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, psql

Could you tell me how to check what indexes are created for some table in postgresql ?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

The view [`pg_indexes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-indexes.html) provides access to useful information about each index in the database, e.g.:

```sql
select *
from pg_indexes
where tablename = 'test'
```

The [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) system view contains more detailed (internal) parameters, in particular, whether the index is a primary key or whether it is unique. Example:

```sql
select 
    c.relnamespace::regnamespace as schema_name,
    c.relname as table_name,
    i.indexrelid::regclass as index_name,
    i.indisprimary as is_pk,
    i.indisunique as is_unique
from pg_index i
join pg_class c on c.oid = i.indrelid
where c.relname = 'test'
```

See examples in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/s47JoGww)

Comment: More of a silly question on my part but your solution will also print the autogenerated indexes of PostgreSQL on the PKs. Any ideas on how to print only the user-specific indexes ?

Comment: @VaggelisManousakis - The [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) system view contains more detailed (internal) parameters, in particular, whether the index is a primary key or whether the index is unique. Note that Postgres does not distinguish *user-specific* from other indexes.
​

Comment: be aware: Table names in pgsql is **case sensitive**.

Answer (score 152):

if you're in psql, then:

```
\d tablename
```

show Indexes, Foreign Keys and references...

Comment: For case sensitive table names, use `\d "Tablename"`

Comment: Much easier to use than having to construct a query!

Comment: i tried `\d tablename` in dbeaver and its not working - `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1

Error position: line: 56` . Is there a way to run it in GUI/DBeaver.

Comment: @samshers : No, it is client feature of `psql`.

Comment: I get `ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ..., c.relhasindex, c.relhasrules, c.relhastriggers, c.relhasoi...` on psql CLI

Answer (score 46):

You can use this query:

`select tablename,indexname,tablespace,indexdef  from pg_indexes where tablename = 'your_table_name'`;

where has **tablename** is a field in **pg_indexes** ,you an get an accurate indices  by matching user defined table at '***your_table_name***' at *WHERE* clause . This will give you the desired details.

Answer (score 9):

The command

```
\di
```

will list all indexes for the current schema.

Answer (score 8):

You can find all the index related information inside the `pg_indexes` view. Sometimes, a table may be part of some schema ("owner") or might have had a different name in the past (see: [PostgreSQL Rename Table](https://orahow.com/postgresql-rename-table/)).

So first find out what is the schema ("owner") of the table:

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='table_name';
```

and then query indexes on the table with either of these queries:

```
SELECT tablename, indexname FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename='table_name';
-- or 
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename='schema_name.table_name';
```

As an alternative to all the above, you can also use \d:

```
\d table_name;
```